# Perl "\my $var" why is the "my" escaped with a backslash?

Tags: perl, syntax, scope, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I was looking at some sample code for making and removing file paths using File::Path.

http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html

I can get the functions to work fine but I have had some difficulty getting the error messaging to work right.  In the example for capturing error messages they use a `\` before the `my`.  What is the purpose of this `\`?

```
# Sample code from the link above
remove_tree( 'foo/bar', 'bar/rat', {error => \my $err} );  # why escape the my?!?!
if (@$err) {
    for my $diag (@$err) {
        my ($file, $message) = %$diag;
        if ($file eq '') {
            print "general error: $message\n";
        }
        else {
            print "problem unlinking $file: $message\n";
        }
    }
}
else {
    print "No error encountered\n";
}
```

I have never seen this before and I can't find an explanation anywhere.  I tried removing the `\` and I get a syntax error so clearly it is needed, but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `my` has higher precedence than `\` in Perl, so it's the whole expression `my $err` which `\` is being applied to.  `\` itself isn't really an escape; to quote http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References :

> References can be created in several ways.
>
> 1. By using the backslash operator on a variable, subroutine, or value. (This works much like the & (address-of) operator in C.) This typically creates another reference to a variable, because there's already a reference to the variable in the symbol table. But the symbol table reference might go away, and you'll still have the reference that the backslash returned.

For example:

```
my $scalarref = \$foo;
```

makes `$scalarref` a reference to the existing scalar variable `$foo`.  By contrast,

```
my $scalarref = \my $foo;
```

creates a new scalar variable `$foo` and makes `$scalarref` a reference to it, which can be more compact.

Answer (score 6):

`\my $err` returns a reference to the new variable `$err`.

`remove_tree` expects the values of the `error` option to be a reference to a scalar. The reference tells `remove_tree` where the errors should be stored. `error => my $err` would pass the value of `$err` (undef) rather than a means of locating `$err`.

Answer (score 4):

```
remove_tree( 'foo/bar', 'bar/rat', {error => \my $err} );
```

is a shorthand way of doing this:

```
my $err;
remove_tree( 'foo/bar', 'bar/rat', {error => \$err} );
```

The `\$err` means "reference to `$err`".